# How to keep a Git repository always updated locally?

Tags: macos, git, github

I use Git Tower to manage my Git repositories on OS X, so I'm looking for an answer which let me use that software or simply the Git cli.

I have some Git (private GitHub) repositories cloned locally, I never work on them but I need them to be always updated because I run the software contained in these repositories (or I use some part of these repositories as dependencies of another repository, no submodule, sorry).

So, I'm looking for a way to keep these repositories always updated. How can I do?

Comment: Sounds like you're creating [a build server](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)?

Comment: No, we have already a CI using jenkins, this is just for my local workflow

Answer (score 0):

Git's main purpuse is not distributing your software, but you could always run `git pull` before reloading your code.

Comment: Yup that'sthe problem, I'd just like to have them always updated without have to remember it.

Comment: @FezVrasta do you need to restart your software after the poll? If you do this than you could just write a script.

Comment: It could work for one of the repositories, but the other one just needs to be updated and nothing more. Or better, it must be updated and then I need to run an additional script to copy these files in another folder (I know it sucks)... So probably I'd need to keep it always updated and run a git hook after the git pull, but the hook is easy to do.

Comment: You could always run the update after a special event (depends on your software), if it is a remote, than you could use GitHubs WebHooks as a trigger or as a workaround you could use a Cronjob.

Comment: I think the cronjob is the only way :/ If there was any git specific way to do so I would have preferred it tho..

Comment: crontab or a launch agent are the way to go. Either way, you need to write a script as these will simply manage the timing of when it's run. You also may want to consider a script so that you can manage what branches to pull and what to do if you have an error. Just saying...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need a combination of tools.

First, you need a way to keep track of the repositories that need updating and update them in one fell swoop. [myrepos](http://myrepos.branchable.com) is a good option for helping with that.

Then you need a way to periodically run the update command, which can be done a variety of ways. There's some good pointers in other comments : `cron`, a launch agent of sorts, etc.

It strikes me, though, that if the repos are updated automatically in the background (w/o user initiation/intervention), you'd want some report/log/email to be generated when the repos are updated, should anything fail or other unexpected conditions occur.

It also should be noted that blindly updating repos and then copying/packaging the updated code for use elsewhere is somewhat risky. IMHO, this problem smells like it needs a proper dependency management tool or package manager.